# Probability distribution in H atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

The electron in an H atom has a state

$$u_{3,1}(r) \left( 
\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}    Y_{1,0} \vert u_{\text{down}}\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}    Y_{1,1} \vert u_{\text{up}}\rangle    
\right)$$

Where $u_{n,l}(r)$ is the radial part and $Y_{l,m}(r)$ is the angular dependence
gives as a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$. The spin part of the condition is shown
in Dirac notation.

> If one were to measure the z-component of the orbital angular momentum
> ($m_z$) measure, what are the possible results and with what
> probabilities?

I think probability 1/3 m = 0 and probability 2/3 m = 1.

Same for the z-component of the spin moment $s_z$.

I think probability 1/3 $s_z = -0.5$ and probability 2/3 $s_z = 0.5$.

> Calculate the probability density to place the electron at a
> well-defined location $\left(r, \theta, \phi\right)$.

How do I get started on the latter? I'm not sure how to account for the spin....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guesses for the first question are correct.

For the latter, you start by remembering that the total probability of finding the electron somewhere in space is $1$ and it's given by:
$$ P = \int_\text{all space} \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{r}\,|\Psi|^2, $$
where $\Psi$ is the wavefunction.

Hence, $|\Psi|^2$ is the probability density.

In your case, you are the spherical basis, so the integral is going to be in spherical coordinates:

$$ P = \int_\text{all space} r^2\mathrm{d}r\,\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}\phi\cdot|\Psi(r, \phi, \theta)|^2, $$

and your probability density is:
$$ |\Psi(r, \phi, \theta)|^2 = u(r)^2_{3,1} \cdot \left ( \frac{1}{3}|Y_{1,0}(\theta, \phi)|^2 +  \frac{2}{3}|Y_{1,1}(\theta, \phi)|^2 \right). $$

Comment: I think you mean 2/3 in the last formula?

Comment: @WimNevelsteen Yes, sorry, fixed it.